# Microservices for shared basic lookup data

Tags: microservices

I am new to microservices, and I need to create a "Student" service, which will get, save and also adds via a webhook from another thirdparty application

However, one of the fields i need to save is "Subject"

Normally, in SQL i would have a subject table, with things like
ID | Subject
1, Maths
2, English
3, Software

which i can use to populate drop down boxes, and in my Student table, i could have "SubjectId" field

However, if using a microservice... how would i setup my student microservice database so its independent?

then, what if I have a "CollegeCourse" service, which also needs the Subject type?

Should they both have there own 2nd database table, but doesnt that run the risk of a miss match... or maybe a nugGet package and just hardcode some enums which i can share between microservices?

Thank you

I can seem to find any suggestions or answers anywhere for this, but,